# Ticking timers in Kendo UI grid

Tags: asp.net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Kinda new to this. I'm trying to implement a Kendo UI grid control in which the data of one of the columns that represents how long a user has been waiting in queue. Imagine a display in a DMV where you have a list of ticket numbers and a running timer next to each representing how long a certain ticket has been pending.

Any pointers on how this functionality can be achieved?

I'm trying to see if I could fire a timer every second, iterate over all rows in the grid when the timer fires and update each row individually. Does that approach sound okay?

Comment: you should reconsider the point to rebind the grid with updated datasource every second, using this approach will also depend on the number of rows that you have and if you are going to use this application on mobile too.

Comment: If you need to increase the waiting time on client only then it should be alright. If you need server data, too, to be able to increase the waiting time I would connect the grid to signalr (http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/signalr)

Comment: Yes, I don't want to refresh the entire data source each time. I just want some way for my javascript to iterate over all `<tr />`s and update the col I need directly.